# Why am seeing only limited options in my byobu?

Tags: byobu

I installed the latest version of byobu by building from the source.

```
byobu version 5.111
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06
```

But I am not able to use many of the options (like: new session, splits, etc) or see them listed in the config menu.

[image: Byobu options that work]

What do I need to do to get all the options working?

[image: Full set of options as listed in the byobu website]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the extended options are available while byobu is using TMUX and only the limited options are available when using SCREEN.

The reason byobu was not starting using TMUX was because it was not installed on the system.

After installing TMUX (by following these steps: https://gist.github.com/ryin/3106801), I am able to get all the extended options!